# How to delete rows per category in pandas based on a specific range? and the range is a string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

I have a dataframe like this,

```
Date           Info 
2022-01-01     egg price
2022-01-01     Central Java
2022-01-01     East Java
2022-01-01     chicken price
2022-01-01     Central Java
2022-01-01     East Java
2022-01-02     egg price
2022-01-02     Central Java
2022-01-02     East Java
2022-01-02     chicken price
2022-01-02     Central Java
2022-01-02     East Java
```

how to delete rows starting from egg price to row before chicken price, and this is per date category.
I want to be like this:

```
Date           Info
2022-01-01     chicken price
2022-01-01     Central Java
2022-01-01     East Java
2022-01-02     chicken price
2022-01-02     Central Java
2022-01-02     East Java
```

Comment: Some problem with my answer?

Answer (score 2):

If per `Date` are only one values `egg` and `chicken` price, `egg` is before `chicken` is possible create mask and get values between with [`GroupBy.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cummax.html):

```
m1 = df['Info'].eq('egg price')
m2 = df['Info'].eq('chicken price')
mask = m1.groupby(df['Date']).cummax() & m2.iloc[::-1].groupby(df['Date']).cummax() & ~m2
df = df[~mask]

print (df)
          Date           Info
3   2022-01-01  chicken price
4   2022-01-01   Central Java
5   2022-01-01      East Java
9   2022-01-02  chicken price
10  2022-01-02   Central Java
11  2022-01-02      East Java
```

Comment: @RizaPurnaramadhan - Do you think `m1.groupby(df['Date']).cummax()` ? It create `True`s value per `Date` after match `m1`, in another words False before `agg price`